# Including AR(1) in growth model makes intercept constant (R nlme)

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, panel-data, multilevel-analysis

I have data of countries, years and some variables as shown below (not the comeplete dataset):

```
df <- structure(list(country = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), continent = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Africa", "Americas", 
"Asia", "Europe", "Oceania"), class = "factor"), year = c(0, 
1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2), lifeExp = c(80.69, 82, 82.603, 77.218, 
78.471, 79.425, 76.81, 77.31, 78.242), pop = c(125956499L, 127065841L, 
127467972L, 58808266L, 59912431L, 60776238L, 272911760L, 287675526L, 
301139947L), gdpPercap = c(28816.58499, 28604.5919, 31656.06806, 
26074.53136, 29478.99919, 33203.26128, 35767.43303, 39097.09955, 
42951.65309)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

  country continent year lifeExp       pop gdpPercap
1       1      Asia    0  80.690 125956499  28816.58
2       1      Asia    1  82.000 127065841  28604.59
3       1      Asia    2  82.603 127467972  31656.07
4       2    Europe    0  77.218  58808266  26074.53
5       2    Europe    1  78.471  59912431  29479.00
6       2    Europe    2  79.425  60776238  33203.26
7       3  Americas    0  76.810 272911760  35767.43
8       3  Americas    1  77.310 287675526  39097.10
9       3  Americas    2  78.242 301139947  42951.65
```

I am interested in looking at how countries `life expectancy` change with `time` or `year`, while adding another predictor -- a **time-varying covariate**, which is `gdpPercap`. I am using a step-by-step model building process by adding complexity to each successive model using the r package `nlme`:

```
randomIntercept <- lme(lifeExp ~ 1, random=~1|country, data=df, method='ML') # random intercept model
yearRI <- lme(lifeExp ~ year, random=~1|country, data=df, method='ML') # add year as fixed effect
ARModel <- update(yearRI, correlation=corAR1()) # include first-order autocorrelation
gdp_tvc <- update(ARModel, .~. + gdpPercap) # adding gdp as time-varying covariate
```

I find that when I include the AR1 into my model (the `ARModel` in my code above), the model **predicts the same intercept (time point 0) for all countries**, but when I exclude it, each country has its own random intercept. However, the `ARModel` actually improves the model fit (from BIC, AIC and log likelihood test), and the subsequent `gdp_tvc model` improves it further.

```
anova(randomIntercept,yearRI,ARModel,gdp_tvc)

                Model df       AIC       BIC     logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
randomIntercept     1  3 255.45957 264.28449 -124.72978                        
yearRI              2  4 188.49772 200.26429  -90.24886 1 vs 2 68.96184  <.0001
ARModel             3  5 141.91039 156.61860  -65.95520 2 vs 3 48.58733  <.0001
gdp_tvc             4  6  54.15592  71.80577  -21.07796 3 vs 4 89.75448  <.0001
```

Summary of `gdp_tvc` model:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
 Data: df 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  54.15592 71.80577 -21.07796

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | country
         (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev: 5.113739e-05 0.3946288

Correlation Structure: AR(1)
 Formula: ~1 | country 
 Parameter estimate(s):
      Phi 
0.7390235 
Fixed effects: lifeExp ~ year + gdpPercap 
                  Value  Std.Error  DF    t-value p-value
(Intercept)  0.30498649 0.08704423 118   3.503810  0.0006
year        -0.05476348 0.02102694 118  -2.604444  0.0104
gdpPercap   -0.06395064 0.00563828 118 -11.342216  0.0000
 Correlation: 
          (Intr) year  
year      -0.562       
gdpPercap -0.101 -0.409

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-3.91563811 -0.62233306 -0.03077388  0.45841649  2.29132880 

Number of Observations: 140
Number of Groups: 20
```

Intercepts for all countries are the same when **including AR(1)**:

```
df %>% mutate(predict = predict(gdp_tvc)) %>% filter(year==0) %>% 
       select(country,year,predict)

   country year   predict
1       20    0 0.3049865
2        3    0 0.3049865
3       19    0 0.3049865
4       18    0 0.3049865
5       17    0 0.3049865
6       16    0 0.3049865
7       14    0 0.3049865
8       13    0 0.3049865
9       11    0 0.3049865
10       9    0 0.3049865
11       8    0 0.3049865
12       7    0 0.3049865
13       6    0 0.3049865
14       5    0 0.3049865
15       4    0 0.3049865
16       2    0 0.3049865
17      15    0 0.3049865
18      12    0 0.3049865
19      10    0 0.3049865
20       1    0 0.3049865
```

Intercepts for all countries are different when `ARModel` is skipped:

```
   country year     predict
1       20    0  0.44962967
2        3    0  0.39230657
3       19    0  0.19300525
4       18    0  0.20016271
5       17    0  0.17377740
6       16    0  0.22038802
7       14    0  0.72431971
8       13    0 -0.18436895
9       11    0  0.33454848
10       9    0  0.30743154
11       8    0  0.42740244
12       7    0  0.22153015
13       6    0 -0.02635835
14       5    0  0.55953753
15       4    0  0.33999809
16       2    0  0.46540934
17      15    0 -0.58126671
18      12    0  0.43051587
19      10    0  0.09283798
20       1    0  0.51549595
```

Just that the intercept is all the same for all countries when the `ARModel` is included. Has anyone experienced this before and know what might be the reason?

Comment: Please can you include the relevant portions of the output from the actual models.